# How to connect remote roscore with python in runtime

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**The following is the implementation using roscpp:**

std::map<std::string, std::string> remappings;

remappings["__master"] = master_url;

remappings["__hostname"] = host_url;

ros::init(remappings, "node name");

**parement "master_url" and "host_url" come from UI**

**So how to  implement using python?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330654/how-to-connect-remote-roscore-with-python-in-runtime/) by [ugluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43039/ugluo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-14**:
Can you please clarify: What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? And please make sure your code is correctly formatted.

**Comment by [ugluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43039/ugluo/) on 2019-08-14**:
I want to connect remote roscore with python, The above code implements the function of connecting to a remote roscore using roscpp.

**Comment by [ugluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43039/ugluo/) on 2019-08-14**:
roscpp:
std::map<std::string, std::string=""> remappings;
remappings["__master"] = master_url;
remappings["__hostname"] = host_url;
ros::init(remappings, "node name");

**Comment by [ugluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43039/ugluo/) on 2019-08-14**:
the rospy project come from catkin_create_qt_pkg

```
catkin_create_qt_pkg test_qt
```

the code in 'src/qnode.cpp' lline 57-59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not familiar with the remapping within the code. The normal way is: You have to set the `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` environment variable in the terminal according to https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup. Then run your python code with rosrun and it will connect to the remote roscore.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ugluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43039/ugluo/) on 2019-08-14**:
Thanks
I know this solution,but I want to implement it in code like roscpp, the parameters come from the UI
I have tried to use os.system("shell commond") but failed,like this:

```
os.system('export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.91:11311 ; echo $ROS_MASTER_URI')
os.system('echo $ROS_MASTER_URI')
```

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-14**:
I see. You could try https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.putenv

**Comment by [ugluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43039/ugluo/) on 2019-08-15**:
Thanks,  the function of os.putenv() can't set the environment on my own running python,just like the way "launch terminal 、set environment and run command",
my rusty code in [link text](https://github.com/uniqueluo/leap-one_gazebo_ajustment/blob/master/gazebo_ajustment.py)

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-15**:
please try `os.putenv("ROS_MASTER_URI", "http://192.168.0.91:11311")` (and the same for ROS_HOSTNAME) then you can check with `print(os.environ)`. This seems to be also how `init_node` gets the params (https://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-pysrc.html#init_node - line 317)

**Comment by [ugluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43039/ugluo/) on 2019-08-15**:
Thank you serserly ,the problem is already solved.

i try to use os.putenv

```
os.putenv("ROS_MASTER_URI", "http://192.168.0.91:11311")
print(os.environ)
self.node =  rospy.init_node('leap_one_gazebo_control', anonymous=True)
print(os.environ)
```

then output:

```
http://localhost:11311
http://localhost:11311
```

so i print the type(os.environ) and Force modify data of the  dictionary

```
os.environ['ROS_MASTER_URI'] = 'http://192.168.0.91:11311'
os.environ['ROS_MASTER_IP'] = '192.168.0.91'
```

tne output

```
http://192.168.0.91:11311
http://192.168.0.91:11311
```

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-15**:
ok, cool. Can you please accept my answer then (click the little check mark)